# (iPhone) Can I do AudioServicesPlaySystemSound Looping with scheduler?

Tags: iphone, audio, loops

Can I do AudioServicesPlaySystemSound Looping with scheduler? One problem is I cannot get the sound duration. Is there any way to get the duration so I can dynamically create a scheduler that loops the sound? As far as I know AudioService does not have built-in looping and other necessry functions, and that's really a pain.

Answer (score 0):

The audio session is different from the thing playing audio.  The session manages mixer levels and the basic routing to different things like headphones and speakers and what-not.  To loop things is a property of the player.

If you don't need the low-level audio stuff, you might be able to get by with [MPMusicPlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) which has a `repeatMode` property you can take advantage of.

Alternatively, there is also the AVAudioPlayer which you can listen for [delegate messages](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerDelegateProtocolReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008068-CH1-SW5) and start the playback once it stops to simulate looping yourself.

Comment: I tried AVAudioPlayer but it didn't work. OpenAL seems to be too complicated for the project. I guess I'll try MPMusicPlayer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use AVAudioPlayer for this, because you can register callbacks with AudioServices, too.

See the answer in [How to vibrate continuously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718837/how-to-run-vibrate-continuously-in-iphone/2718906#2718906); just replace the vibrate SystemSoundID with your own sound.