# About MPMusicPlayerController and does AVAudioPlayer works in iPhoneSimulator?

Tags: ios-simulator, avaudioplayer, mpmusicplayercontroller

From [(iPhone) Can I do AudioServicesPlaySystemSound Looping with scheduler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111866/iphone-can-i-do-audioservicesplaysystemsound-looping-with-scheduler)

MPMusicPlayerController doesn't work because it is about iPod music library and I can't add a music file to it since I'm doing an iPhone game and not interacting with the outside iPod library.

Does AVAudioPlayer works in iPhoneSimulator?

Answer (score 1):

Check out following code its a simple AVAudioPlayer example and its work on iPhone simulator too ..

AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/azan1.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

NSError *error;
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;

[audioPlayer play];
```