# how to run vibrate continuously in iphone?

Tags: iphone

In my application I'm using following coding pattern to vibrate my iPhone device

Include: `AudioToolbox` framework

Header File:

```
#import "AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h"
```

Code:

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

My problem is that when I run my application it gets vibrate but only for second but I want that it will vibrate continuously until I will stop it.

How could it be possible?

Comment: As I live and breath, I hope that this cannot be done :) Please never cause your application to vibrate my phone non-stop :D

Comment: "Nudge, Nudge, wink wink, Say no more"

Comment: Coming soon to the app store... the iBrator

Comment: @aman-gupta, Hi.
U only need to run your vibrate function on NSThread until and unless the user pressing the stop button(whenever the user click on stop button your thread should be stop).
Best luck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are numerous examples that show how to do this with a private CoreTelephony call: `_CTServerConnectionSetVibratorState`, but it's really not a sensible course of action since your app **will** get rejected for abusing the vibrate feature like that. Just don't do it.

Answer (score 23):

Thankfully, it's not possible to change the duration of the vibration.  The only way to trigger the vibration is to play the `kSystemSoundID_Vibrate` as you have.  If you really want to though, what you can do is to repeat the vibration indefinitely, resulting in a pulsing vibration effect instead of a long continuous one. To do this, you need to register a callback function that will get called when the vibration sound that you play is complete:

```
 AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion (
        kSystemSoundID_Vibrate,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        MyAudioServicesSystemSoundCompletionProc,
        NULL
    );
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

Then you define your callback function to replay the vibrate sound again:

```
#pragma mark AudioService callback function prototypes
void MyAudioServicesSystemSoundCompletionProc (
   SystemSoundID  ssID,
   void           *clientData
);

#pragma mark AudioService callback function implementation

// Callback that gets called after we finish buzzing, so we 
// can buzz a second time.
void MyAudioServicesSystemSoundCompletionProc (
   SystemSoundID  ssID,
   void           *clientData
) {
  if (iShouldKeepBuzzing) { // Your logic here...
      AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate); 
  } else {
      //Unregister, so we don't get called again...
      AudioServicesRemoveSystemSoundCompletion(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
  }  
}
```

Comment: @jason Jenkins: isholdKeepbuzzing is local variable or global variable. my bool variable is not accepting even i declared ad __block

Answer (score 1):

Read the Apple Human Interaction Guidelines for iPhone. I believe this is not approved behavior in an app.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 5 has implemented Custom Vibrations mode. So in some cases variable vibration is acceptable. The only thing is unknown what library deals with that (pretty sure not CoreTelephony) and if it is open for developers. So keep on searching.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are good and you can do it in a simple way also.

You can use the recursive method calls.

```
func vibrateTheDeviceContinuously() throws {
        
        // Added concurrent queue for next & Vibrate device
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async {
            
            //Vibrate the device
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)

            self.incrementalCount += 1
            usleep(800000) // if you don't want pause in between, remove this line.

            do {
                if let isKeepBuzzing = self.iShouldKeepBuzzing , isKeepBuzzing == true {
                    try self.vibrateTheDeviceContinuously()
                }
                 else {
                    return 
                 }
                
            } catch  {
                //Exception handle
               print("exception")
            }
            
        }
    }
```

To stop the device vibration use the following line.

```
self.iShouldKeepBuzzing = false
```

[ios](/questions/tagged/ios) [swift](/questions/tagged/swift)