# Making the iPhone vibrate continuously till the button is pressed

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am trying to make the phone vibrate for the duration till the user keeps a button pressed. I am able to make it vibrate with the user touches it once using `AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))` but that generates 0.4 seconds of vibration followed by 0.1 seconds of silence.

Is there any way I can produce a continuous vibration for, say 3 seconds, while the the user keeps pressing the button? And also, how to implement this only till the user is pressing the button?

And yes, I know that Apple will reject this app if I submit it to the App Store, so please refrain from telling me that.

Comment: Have a look to this question . I dont think it can happen due to Apple Human Interaction guideline http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718837/how-to-run-vibrate-continuously-in-iphone

Comment: have you use, #import <AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>?

Comment: And try to use this, AudioServicesPlaySystemSound.

Comment: @KAR yes, I am using `import AudioToolbox` but as I said, I can only produce pulses by that.

Comment: @KAR tried `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound`. Same result.