# SwiftUI: How to make phone vibrate?

Tags: swift, swiftui, iphone-vibrate

So I understand how to make the phone give haptic feedback through this tutorial.
https://swifttom.com/2020/03/11/haptic-feedback-in-a-swiftui-button/

However, what I'm trying to figure out is how to make the iPhone actually vibrate, as in the vibration that occurs when receiving a phone call or a timer (from the default Clock app) going off while the phone is muted. I know this seems like I can find the answer easily on Google, but I honestly can't find a solution. Would be much appreciate if anyone can help.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let generator = UINotificationFeedbackGenerator()
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Button("Press") {
                generator.notificationOccurred(.error) //I want vibration, not haptic feedback
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this help? [how to run vibrate continuously in iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66040992/7129318)

Comment: I just now looked over the link you provided. I haven't actually tried it out, but it looks like a valid solution. However, the solution I accepted here seems to be a more simple solution that uses less code.

Comment: It is the answer from the link that I provided. Everyone simply googled it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should help a little I think. Try it out! Lmk if it works!

**Source Code**

```
import SwiftUI
import AudioToolbox


struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            
            Button("Press"){
                AudioServicesPlayAlertSoundWithCompletion(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)) {   }
               
            }
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just call `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)`. You may need to import the AudioToolbox framework.

Comment: Hey, this is the solution I ended up going with. Thanks for the reply. I ended up choosing thetechie's similar answer, however, as it seemed more complete and therefore has more potential to help out future users. I still upvoted your post, though.

Answer (score -1):

**1.** first you need to import **AudioToolbox**

i'm using vibration functionality when i tap button.

> @IBAction func startVibration(_ sender: Any) {
> for _ in 1...5 {
> AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)
> sleep(1)
> } }

its work fine.

**2.** make it an extension on UIDevice?

> extension UIDevice {
> static func vibrate() {
> AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)
> } }

Now you can just call UIDevice.vibrate() as needed.

Comment: This will not help him because he is using SwiftUI

Comment: Can you add some examples of usage? Also, can you link to documentation at all? If you can it'd be a good addition to your answer.