# How do I loop a sound for an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am trying to loop my sound file and I cannot find the parameter to loop the sound file! I'm about to pull out the last standing hair on my head. It loads fine....it plays....I just can't figure out the code on how to make it loop.

Here is my code:

```
NSString *eyeBGPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"theeye" ofType:@"caf"];
CFURLRef eyeBGURL = (CFURLRef ) [NSURL fileURLWithPath:eyeBGPath];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(eyeBGURL, &eyeBackGroundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(eyeBackGroundID);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

I found this:

loops
Indicates whether the receiver restarts playback when it reaches the end of its content. Default: NO.

```
- (BOOL)loops
Return Value
```

YES when the receiver restarts playback when it finishes, NO otherwise.

Availability
Available in Mac OS X v10.5 and later.
See Also
– setLoops:
Declared In
NSSound.h

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSound_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSSound/loops

I'm confused on how to implement this.

Comment: IS IT A REALLY LOUD SOUND? (Please don't use all caps in your question titles).

Comment: Sorry, all. I normally do not spend my time on online forums, so I am unfamiliar with THE CAPS thing and that someone considers that yelling. Apologies.

Comment: No worries, now you know. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code that worked for me. If anyone needs help with this, let me know. Someone on the Apple Dev forum pointed me to the AVFoundation docs.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/theeye3.caf", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:NULL];
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;

[audioPlayer play];
```

Here is code to pick out a sound file based on a random number from an image array.

```
NSString *audioWiz = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%d.caf", randNum];

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:[@"%@/" stringByAppendingString:audioWiz], [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:NULL];
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;
audioPlayer.volume = 0.1;

[audioPlayer play];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer you are looking for is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2111866/3009).

Short answer, use a `MPMusicPlayerController`.

Comment: NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/theeye3.caf", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
    
 //NSError *error;
 audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:NULL];
 audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
    
        [audioPlayer play];     This code works.